# Is it possible to use spread operator in generics parameters?

Tags: typescript

For example with ReactQuery's `useQuery<TQueryFnData = unknown, TError = unknown, TData = TQueryFnData, TQueryKey extends QueryKey = QueryKey>`, I want do like;

```js
type QueryTypeParams = [Record<string, number>, unknown, unknown, "aKey" as const]

const {data} = useQuery<...QueryTypeParams>(
  "anotherKey", // <- expects typescript error
  () => {...}
)
```

But the compiler saids

> Variable 'QueryTypeParams' implicitly has an 'any' type.

at where I use spread operator.

Is there any way to pass generics parameters at once?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible at the moment but there is a [discussion about this feature on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39648).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I do not think it is possible to pass generics parameters at once. You have to provide every type separately.